# Recaptcha not showing up on ipad to mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Google recaptcha disappears when i hit ipad size in my browser my website is https://tvstartup.com.

**What I have tried**

I inspected the div that displays the recaptcha but there's not display: none property or any properties the should make it not display. I also tried using margin to see if it had gone of the screen or something but it did not i also made sure that their was not javascript stopping it from displaying but their is not.

Html:

```
<form action="http://tvstartup.com" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate" id="homeebook">
                    <p class="error" style="color: red;"><?php if (isset($_GET['message'])) {echo $_GET['message'];} ?></p>
                    <p><label>Name (required)<br />
                        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['yourname'])) {echo $_SESSION['yourname'];} ?>" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label>Email (required)<br />
                        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['youremail'])) {echo $_SESSION['youremail'];} ?>" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span></label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>
                            Areas of interest (required)<br />
                            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-738">
                                <select name="menu-738" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                                    <option value="">---</option>
                                    <option value="Internet TV" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['areas'])) {if($_SESSION['areas'] == 'Internet TV'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Internet TV</option>
                                    <option value="Satellite TV" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['areas'])) {if($_SESSION['areas'] == 'Satellite TV'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Satellite TV</option>
                                    <option value="Cable TV" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['areas'])) {if($_SESSION['areas'] == 'Cable TV'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Cable TV</option>
                                    <option value="Consulting" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['areas'])) {if($_SESSION['areas'] == 'Consulting'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Consulting</option>
                                    <option value="Other" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['areas'])) {if($_SESSION['areas'] == 'Other'){echo 'selected';}} ?>>Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </p>

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey"></div>

                             <p><input type="submit" value="Send Ebook" name="submitebook" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"/></p>
                                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Please Help me Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your page code and problem is not in styling of recapcha, but in containers that include it:

[containers of small version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdM4C.png)

[containers of big version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhwH7.png)

It seem that after resizing, one container disappears, when second appears. And obviously one of the containers doesn't have captcha. It's why that thing disappears.

EDIT:

Insert:

```
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdThiUUAAAAADHuhJfixVu5tZyeuOrXJKYcj4O4"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="so_pliki/anchor.htm" title="widżet reCAPTCHA" scrolling="no" name="undefined" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea></div></div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdThiUUAAAAADHuhJfixVu5tZyeuOrXJKYcj4O4"></div>
```

I was looking for it for 2h. For future, please make your code clear and readable for anybody, because reading it is extremely tough.

Comment: Do you use any js to develop responsive design or it's only css?

Comment: i think it is a little js to

Comment: Ok. It's not my favourite thing to look at code in any browser.
I suggest adding recaptcha to carousel_data class container. It's all.

Comment: If you have any problem with id of captcha element use jquery methods to move recaptcha from class to class. (use can use append(), prepend(), before() or after() methods to do that. See http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: Give me a few seconds